# How to get last modified date of folder inclusive of changes to child folders/files with Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I created a dropdown in my application that displays folders in a Google Drive based on a user's search. The dropdown shows both the name of the folder and the last modified date. However, Google does not update the last modified date of the parent folder when any of it's child folders/files are modified, it only updates in response to direct modifications to that specific folder. I've thought of two possible solutions, but I'm not really of fan of either and am looking for some other more performant/efficient solutions.

For example,

1. After receiving the results from the user's query I could iterate over each result (i.e. each parent folder) and fetch a list of all it's children and then iterate through the last modified date for each child to return the most recent date. However, performing this on each autocomplete query would be slow and degrade the user experience as the user would have to wait for a few seconds after typing before the results load.
2. I could have a separate background process outside of my application that runs every 1 minute and checks for file changes using the *Changes: list* resource and filters the changes that are related to the root folder where the dropdown options live. However, to do this I need to recursively travel up the parent tree to get to the root folder for each change because only the direct parent (not other ancestors) are accessible in the "parents" property of the File resource. I'd have to do this for each change just to determine if the change was related to a subfolder/file of the root folder (2-3 levels up). Which means each change would require another 2-3 api requests just to determine if it is even relevant. Keep in mind the number of changes in the change list is quite large.

Both of these solutions while viable seem pretty inefficient to me. Does anyone have a better suggestion as to how I can achieve this objective?

Comment: Can you explain more in depth how your application works? If you know from it that a user has made a change, why not update the parents directly? The structure of your folder is static? Also, have you considered posting a [Feature Request for Drive API](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191650&template=824106) that allows to "auto-update" parents last-modified time?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Emel. The changes made to the Google Drive files/folders happen outside of the application (the files are saved from within a desktop application which then syncs to the drive with Google Drive desktop). The folders/files are read-only from within my web app. Yes, the structure is relatively static, however there are still multiple level depths within that structure regarding which files should trigger an update to the parents last-modified time. Lastly, that's a good idea to post a feature request, however I know it will not happen within my required timeline. Any ideas?

Comment: The only way I know of to update the "last modified" date of a folder is to rename the folder. So, a hack is to rename the folder twice (change it to something else, then change it back to its correct name) every time you change a file contained in the folder.

Comment: It's a shame this isn't a feature at this point. The fact that "last modified time" does not respect children makes it much more difficult for me to find what I need.

Comment: I want to do this from the terminal too

Comment: We should write an openletter to google drive asking them to implement it!